# Derivation of wave equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, string, continuum-mechanics, coupled-oscillators

I learned that the wave equation derivation is below.
Suppose $q$ is the displacement on $y$ component, $T$ is string tension, $d$ is the interval of two particles in $x$ direction.

Equation of motion
$$
m \frac{d^2q_j}{dt^2}=\frac {T}{d}(q_{j+1}-q_j)+\frac {T}{d}(q_{j-1}-q_j)  \\q_{j+1}-q_{j}=>q(x+dx)-q(x)
$$
From Taylor expansion
$$
q(x+dx)-q(x)=\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}d+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 q}{\partial x^2}d^2+...\\q_{j-1}-q_{j}=q(x-dx)-q(x)=\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}(-d)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 q}{\partial x^2}(-d)^2+...
$$
In continuous situation, I'm looking at a specific position, that is
$$
m \frac{d^2q_j}{dt^2}=>m \frac{\partial^2q_j}{\partial t^2}
$$
Then combine the Taylor expansion to second order
$$
m \frac{\partial^2q_j}{\partial t^2}=\frac {T}{d}\frac{\partial^2 q}{\partial x^2}(d)^2
$$
set u is linear mass density, and m=ud
$$
\frac{\partial^2q_j}{\partial t^2}=\frac {T}{u}\frac{\partial^2 q}{\partial x^2}
$$

My question:
When I calculate the tension force, why don't I need to consider the time term?
since q is the function of x and t, so my taylor expansion might like this?
$$
q(x+dx,t+dt)-q(x,t)
$$
because the left hand side of equation of motion only consider fixing at x=x position. I don't fix the time term.

Although I could think of that the tension force is like I take a photo of this string, and observe the dynamic motion. Won't I consider the tension is changing with time too?

Comment: The assumption is that the local stretching that takes place in the string elements as a result of the string displacements is small enough to produce negligible change in the local tension.  You can check this a priori  by considering the deformational kinematics of the string motion.

Answer (score 1):

When applying Newton's IInd law, you're relating the acceleration of that particular particle of the string with the forces applied on it at a particular instant in time. The acceleration, at that time, is proportional to the sum of the forces on the particle, at that time.

In this particular case, the tension force is proportional to the separation between the particle and its neighbours.

Essentially,

$$
q_{j+1}-q_{j} \Rightarrow q(x+dx)-q(x)
$$

secretly means

$$
q_{j+1,k}-q_{j, k} \Rightarrow q(x+dx, t)-q(x, t),
$$

where $ k $ is an index labelling time. Note there's no need to Taylor expand in time because there's no $ dt $ to expand in.

If instead you'd had

$$
q_{j+1, k+1}-q_{j, k} \Rightarrow q(x+dx, t+dt)-q(x, t),
$$

that would mean the force between the particles wasn't proportional to their separation. In fact it's not clear what it would mean at all. The force is proportional to the separation between... where the particle is right now, and where its neighbour will be in some small time later?

Comment: Then I have a further question, since the forced oscillation equation is $$
\ddot x+\beta\dot x+\omega_0^2x=Acos(\omega t)
$$The force is function of t, where is the particular instant in time of force? @Movpasd

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. At every instant in time, the acceleration, velocity and position are combined as seen on the left hand side. If using finite differences the velocity and acceleration will require using indices $ i+1 $ and $ i+2 $ respectively where $ i $ indexes time. For the right hand side simply substitute in the value of $ t $ corresponding to $ i $. @Yui

Answer (score 0):

You're interested in the net force on an element of string at a particular time *t*. That is determined by the curvature of the string at time *t*. How that curvature will change with time is irrelevant.

Comment: But for forced oscillation equation, the force could be the function of time (like the comment above). If I always care in a particular time t, why not always just solve with an impulse force (like an instant force)? Or actually I'm doing this thing, but I have to add up all the impulse response results like $$x_{f1}(t)+x_{f2}(t)+...=x(t)$$  for final solution. So eventually for easily, I could just solve the equation on a force with time variable? @Philip Wood

Comment: The resultant force on an arbitrary element of string is due to the neighbouring elements, and is proportional to the second derivative of the transverse displacement with respect to $x$. Applying Newton's second law you get the wave equation$$\frac{\partial ^{2}y}{\partial t^2}={\frac{T}{ \rho}} \frac{\partial ^{2}y}{\partial x^2}.$$ This equation shows that any waveform (sinusoid, square wave, single pulse...) will travel at the same speed, $\sqrt{\frac{T}{ \rho}}$, on the string. So you don't need to consider the waveform at the $start$ of your analysis, as you seem to want to do.